# Android: Strange error opening pdf in webview with google drive view

Tags: android

I'm trying to open a PDF in a webview using this code:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view_container);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);

    webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.adobe.com/products/pdfjobready/pdfs/pdftraag.pdf");
```

The webview loads the toolbar from google docs viewer, loads the correct amount of pages but it does not show any content from pdf. (the screen flashes 1 or 2 times).

In log i've seen some strange info:

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated."
[INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "maximum-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated."
[INFO:CONSOLE(6)] "Viewport argument value "no;" for key "user-scalable" is invalid, and has been ignored. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated."
[INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported                                                                                                                  
[INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: I don't have any solution for this yet, because this works correctly in older android versions, but i've noticed that in android 4.4.2 even gmail pdf's have the same problem. I'm testing this in a nexus 7 2013.
I'm starting to think this is a KitKat issue, and it may be solved in a future update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever page is loading in that webview, it have meta tags with invalid syntax. probably using `;` as a separator instead of `,` from the errors... see http://alxgbsn.co.uk/2011/11/23/make-sure-to-use-correct-meta-viewport-syntax/ for more information.